# Java If and else simplification

Tags: java

I have this very long if and else statement, any idea how i would be able to shorten this?

Or is this going to be the only way for me to handle this?

```
if (HR < 41) {
    HR_Score = 2;
} else if (HR < 51) {
    HR_Score = 1;
} else if (HR < 101) {
    HR_Score = 0;
} else if (HR < 111) {
    HR_Score = 1;
} else if (HR < 129) {
    HR_Score = 2;
} else {
    HR_Score = 3;
}
```

Comment: Is `HR` an `int`? And is this the entire thing, or does it go on longer and you've shortened it for the question?

Comment: Yes HR is an int

Comment: Thanks. I sneaked a further question into that comment you may not have seen yet. :-)

Comment: This is the entire thing, i just feel like its way too long and ugly coding.

Comment: I wonder if this is too opinion-based for SO's format.

Comment: I dont unerstand?

Comment: It's ugly, but it's crystal clear what you're doing - anyone can understand it in mere seconds - wrap it in a method with meaningful name and move on.

Comment: Thanks, was just wondering. i am wrapping it and moving on. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `? :` operator to make the code shorter:

```
int HR_Score = HR < 41   ? 2 : 
              (HR < 51)  ? 1 : 
              (HR < 101) ? 0 : 
              (HR < 111) ? 1 : 
              (HR < 129) ? 2 :
                           3;
```

The conditional operator (aka "ternary" because it takes three operands) is a convenient way of chaining if/else statements that you don't care to nest.

Comment: I like this one

Comment: I find this one to be more confusing than the standard if/else approach, especially for those who are not used to conditional operator. Chaining multiple conditional operators could easily confuse them, and code would be less maintainable.

Answer (score 10):

You can solve your problem with NavigableMap. For example:

```
// In the class
private static final NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(41, 2);
map.put(51, 1);
map.put(101, 0);
map.put(111, 1);
map.put(129, 2);
map.put(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 3);

// When you need a score
HR_Score = map.ceilingEntry(HR).getValue();
```

Comment: Tailored the code to fit the OP's example more closely.

Comment: While I still find the `if`/`else` much clearer than the above, this is at least a viable alternative, unlike several of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really just those six possibilities, that `if`/`else` is just fine, and I wouldn't expect any of the alternatives to be clearer.

I'd stick with the `if`/`else`.

One example of an alternative that's not better: :-)

If `HR` has a relatively narrow range, you could do a lookup table instead.

```
private static final int[] scores = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, /*...*/ 1, /*...*/ 0, /*...*/};
```

then when you need a score:

```
if (HR >= 0 && HR < scores.length) {
    HR_Score = scores[HR];
}
```

..but that's more complex than what you have, and harder to read.

Alternately, a map giving the range and value:

```
private static int[][] scoreLookup = {
    {41, 2},
    {51, 1},
    {101, 0},
    {111, 1},
    {129, 2},
    {Integer.MAX_VALUE, 3}
};
```

and then

```
for (int[] entry : scoreLookup) {
    if (HR < entry[0]) {
        HR_Score = entry[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

...but I still prefer your `if`/`else`.

Comment: I have no idea if the new pattern matching coming in whatever next java version will support this in the form of `case ( x < 41) break 2`, but it would be very nice if it would

Comment: or even better : `case(x < 41) -> 2`

Comment: @Eugene: Yeah, if they make it concise enough. In JavaScript, case labels can be expressions and they're tested in order, so you could use a `switch` here in JavaScript, but `switch` is so verbose it's generally no improvement over the `if`/`else`. :-)

Comment: could not agree more, it seems from the current status, that this is indeed much simplified and easier (much?) to use...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** 
*I recommend using [status answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256034/java-if-and-else-simplification/49256543#49256356) over this. Leaving this here because it poses an alternative way to get tot he same result.*

You can use a Sorted Map with Integers defined by key.

Since you have an exit early strategy, a value can only come in place when the previous tests have failed, we can return early in a loop.

A map exits out of pairs, a key and a value. You can iterate these key value sets and then use that entry set as a comparing function.

I used TreeMap below as implementation, because then we can be relatively sure that the sort order is the order of insertion.

See it live: https://ideone.com/3J3Fqs

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Ideone one = new Ideone();
        System.out.println("41:2="+one.getScore(41));
        System.out.println("50:1="+one.getScore(50));
        System.out.println("101:0="+one.getScore(101));
        System.out.println("110:1="+one.getScore(110));
        System.out.println("128:2="+one.getScore(128));
        System.out.println("200:3="+one.getScore(200));
    }
        private SortedMap<Integer, Integer> pairList = null;

       public SortedMap<Integer, Integer> getPairList() {
           if(pairList == null) {
               pairList = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
               pairList.put(42,2);
               pairList.put(51,1);
               pairList.put(101,0);
               pairList.put(111,1);
               pairList.put(129,2);
           }
           return pairList;
       }

    public int getScore(int compare) {
       for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : this.getPairList().entrySet()) {
           Integer key = entry.getKey();
           if(compare < key) {
               return entry.getValue();
           }

       }
       return 3;

    }
}
```

As an unrelated comment: I suggest you stay away from "magic numbers"/"hardcoded numbers". Try to see if you can put them in a settings file or a database and load them from there.
This will make your application more future proof and easier to change values without having to recompile and redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

you can also look at my version of solutions.

```
//solution1:
     if (HR < 41)  HR_Score = 2;
else if (HR < 51)  HR_Score = 1;
else if (HR < 101) HR_Score = 0;
else if (HR < 111) HR_Score = 1;
else if (HR < 129) HR_Score = 2;
else               HR_Score = 3;


//solution2:
if (HR < 41)  HR_Score = 2; else 
if (HR < 51)  HR_Score = 1; else 
if (HR < 101) HR_Score = 0; else 
if (HR < 111) HR_Score = 1; else 
if (HR < 129) HR_Score = 2; else 
              HR_Score = 3;


//no branch solution.
HR_Score = 3 - (HR < 129)
             - (HR < 111)
             - (HR < 101)
             + (HR < 51)
             + (HR < 41);
```